# Jquery row and column total and percent from total calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of working code.
And it would be great to have percent from Total for every column. The source of the code is from stackoverflow and it is slightly modified not written by me as i am new in jquery.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

```js
<script data-relocate="true">
$('.muestreo').bind({
    keyup:function(){ 
       //Row Total Calculation
  $(".muestreo tr:not(:first, last) td:last-child").text(function () {
   var totalVal = 0;
   $(this).prevAll().each(function () {
    totalVal += parseFloat($(this).children('.muestreo').val()) || 0;
    //totalVal += parseInt( );
   });
   return totalVal.toFixed(2);
  });
   //Column Total Calculation
  $(".muestreo tr:last td").text(function (i) {
   var totalVal = 0;
   $(this).parent().prevAll().find("td:nth-child(" + (++i) + ")").each(function () {
    totalVal += parseFloat($(this).children('.muestreo').val()) || 0;
    $(".muestreo tr:last td:first").text('Sum');
   });
   return totalVal.toFixed(2);
  });
  
   var count=0
    for(i=1;i<$('tr').length;i++){
     var trs=parseFloat($('tr:eq('+i+')').find('td:last').text())
     count+=trs
    }
    $(".muestreo tr:last td:last").text(count)
  }
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Not sure about what the element with the class muestreo is. Is it actually possible to trigger the event? Maybe you could add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example including you HTML, which would make everything a bit more clear.

Comment: The calculations are made on div class and td class. Anyway i just need a jquery code that can do the thing row and column total and percent from total calculation. The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/h8np9qnc/ Thank you

Comment: I build an example for you how to calculate rows and cols total values. Take a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/3k30yxtd/
I would suggest that you clean up your HTML code and apply anything you need from the example. Change the selectors as you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer...but as it can be seen i have the row and column calculations, what i need is a percent calculation for every column from the total sum on the row before last row.

Comment: Just take a look at my example. You can select the total result or select the totals for each col/row by a combination of my selectors. The percentage is calculated through val/total * 100.

Comment: ;) Still don't know how to do it. As i said before i am a total beginner in jquery and my code source was from stackoverflow. I see in the fiddle that your code works very good but i don't know how to use it. After i put in the selectors as i think ;) it is giving me nAns on allmost all the tables from my form ;)

Comment: hello...please help...don't know what to do now

Comment: If you don't know how to find correct selectors I recommend you to read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). I'm sorry but your HTML syntax is a bit confusing. Maybe you can get rid of all the inline css and use the classes you defined to style your table.

Comment: Hi. I have cleaned the html and created a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nnnLf4zf if you can help me please do it.

Comment: You are missing the cell for the total sum. Add it, give it a special ID e.g. `totalSum`and just take every nth col of the `Suma row` and put the result of your calculation into the corresponding nth cell of the `percentage row`. You already applied code to select the nth child of something, so this should help you.